# permutations acting on lists of length n

Tags: algorithm, haskell

In math, when I want to rearrange a list of length n, I'll act on the list with a permutation. For example:

```
(1 2) * (x, y, z) = (y, x, z)
(1 n 2) * (v[1], v[2], ..., v[n]) = (v[n], v[1], ..., v[2])
perm * (v[1], v[2], ..., v[n]) = ( v[perm(1)], v[perm(2)], ..., v[perm(n)] )
```

How would I do this in Haskell?

Comment: That's the usual definition of perm, right? `perm :: {1,2...,N} -> {1,2...,N}` a bijection and so on. A O(N^2) algorithm should be rather simple, but your input in `(1 n 2)` is a rotational one, not a bijection. So decide: what's your actual input?

Comment: @Zeta Whenever `n` is bigger than `3`, `(1 n 2)` is a bijection that maps `1 |-> n`, `n |-> 2`, `2 |-> 1`, and all other values to themselves.

Comment: @DanielWagner which is what I meant with "rotational one" :). I don't recall the correct term for that kind of writing a permutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the input permutation to build a map from old indices to new indices.

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import qualified Data.Map as M

infixr 5 * -- right-associative so we can compose permutations conveniently

(*) :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
perm * xs = zipWith (\i _ -> xs !! M.findWithDefault i i ixMap) [0..] xs
    where ixMap = M.fromList (zip perm (drop 1 perm ++ take 1 perm))
```

You can see it in action in the ghci prompt (though as usual in programming it uses 0-based rather than 1-based indexing):

```
> [0,1] * "xyz"
"yxz"
> [0,4,1] * "abcde"
"eacdb"
```

This costs O(n^2 log m) where n is the length of `xs` and m is the length of `perm`. You can reduce this to O(n log(nm)) by switching from `(!!)` to `M.lookup` for the indexing into `xs`, too.

Comment: It would probably be nicer to have some sort of `[a] -> [a]` new type to represent your permutation since then you could compose permutations. Something allowing (more or less) `cycle [1,2,3] . cycle [3,7] $ [1..10]`.

Comment: @Alec What's wrong with `[1,2,3] * [3,7] * [1..10]`?

Comment: @Alec (Or, if you really must, `cycle = (*)`, and then your syntax works just fine with no further newtypes nonsense.)

Comment: Ah yes. With your last fixity update, `cycle = (*)` is a clever idea.